# how to write shell script to search text in list of directories

Tags: linux, shell

i have to write a shell script by name check.sh to search text in list of directories. The following shell script works properly.

```
find . | xargs grep 'def wander' --color -n
```

But while passing arguments to this grep, not working properly.

```
str='def wander'
find . | xargs grep $str --color -n
```

it accepts only 'def' not 'def wander'. what is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

```
str='def wander'
find . | xargs grep "$str" --color -n
```

But note that you can get the same result without the `find` command:

```
grep --color -rn "def wander" .
```